# is a seriously corroded driveshaft and u joints on an F150 safe? dealer who sold me car says no

Tags: ford, safety, rust, f-150, drivetrain

I think a corroded drive train this corroded is a safety issue, bought used f150 from dealer get out on highway and was scared to hell whole truck shook so bad -drove truck back later same day saying no way is this safe and you just put inspection sticker on it and obviously nobody test drove it but dealer said wasn't a safety problem, refused to cooperate or allow me to get out of rip off deal they pulled on me.

[image: unsafe drivetrain]

Comment: Confused, did the dealer say it was safe or not safe, you have given just about every option... please edit for clarity.

Comment: If they gave you a warranty then yes they should take care of it, but most used vehicles are sold "as is".

Comment: They are in such bad condition I doubt that's the only problem...

Comment: It looks like it was in a flood. Much more rust than I saw in Chicago where salt is used on the streets. I would be concerned about what other flood damage there may be. It would be easy enough to replace the U -joints if that is the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not safe.  Not in my opinion anyway.  That could seize or break at any time causing an accident involving just your vehicle or other vehicles.

It looks to be far beyond reparable condition.  Just get a new driveshaft installed.

Comment: Going to need a new pinion yoke and fasteners also.